# Zur Qual werden | zur Frau werden

Tags: difference, grammar-identification

Ich habe die Sätze "zur Qual werden", "zur Frau werden" gesehen,
und ich möchte es verstehen, warum es hier "zur" gibt, anstatt einfach "zu" oder "zu einer". Wenn man von keinem bestimmten Object redet, warum soll es **zu der** sein?

Comment: Great question - once again something that I never noticed until it's pointed out. Ultimately the answer can only be that 'zur' can be a contraction of 'zu einer' as well as of 'zu der', even though most grammars mention only the latter rule.

Comment: There are even fixed phrases like *zur Last fallen*, *zur Ruhe setzen*, *zur Schau stellen*, which work better when expanding *zur* as *zu einer*.

Comment: I like the explanation by Kilian, but I see also another possibility: *zur* could anyway be a contraction of *zu der*, and the focus of the person speaking is very specifically on that one pain or that one woman; so that it is implicitly supposed that the topic is known between participants of the communication, as in: *Sie ist zu der Frau geworden, die sie heute ist*, or *Das ist zu der Qual geworden, die es eben ist*. In other words, this can be seen as a form of emphasis.

Comment: Thinking about it: could *Qual* / *Frau* be used as [Abstraktum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraktum) here, where even the definite article does not lead to a specific e. g. Frau?

Comment: @guidot Ich denke, das Beispiel _zur Ruhe setzen_ passt nicht wirklich in die Reihe, da es nicht irgendeine Ruhe ist, sondern _die_ Ruhe nach dem Arbeitsleben, sozusagen.

Answer (score 11):

Die Frage ist gut, in gewisser Weise aber trotzdem falsch gestellt, weil sie *zu der* und *zur* gleichsetzt. Es ist aber zwar richtig, dass *zur* aus der Verschmelzung von *zu* und *der* resultiert - dennoch sind die beiden Formen nicht immer austauschbar. Vielmehr gibt es Situationen, in denen keine Verschmelzung möglich ist oder aber nur die verschmolzene Form verwendet werden kann. Ein Beispiel für letzteren Fall sind Funktionsverbgefüge, worauf schon in einem Kommentar aufmerksam gemacht worden ist (*zur Last fallen, zur Ruhe setzen, zur Schau stellen*; niemals: **zu der Last fallen* etc.).

Eine obligatorische Verschmelzung besteht nach *Nübling* in Duden, Die Grammatik, 8. Aufl. 2009, Rn. 925, unter anderem auch in folgendem Fall (Hervorhebung nicht im Original):

> - **vor generisch verwendeten Substantiven, die die Klasse und nicht das Einzelobjekt bezeichnen**: die Entwicklung vom (*von dem) Wolf zum (*zu dem) Hund; die Entwicklung zur Wespe; die Zellteilung beim Menschen; die Ausbildung zum Künstler. (Eine Auflösung kann hier, wenn überhaupt, eher mit dem unbestimmten Artikel vollzogen werden: *die Ausbildung zum (zu einem) Künstler*.)

Dabei darf die Bekanntheit des Referenten nicht auf frühere sprachliche Mitteilungen zurückgehen; er muss als Klasse schon anderweitig bekannt sein. (*Haberland*, [Zum Problem der Verschmelzung von Präposition und bestimmtem Artikel im Deutschen](https://www.academia.edu/698323/Zum_Problem_der_Verschmelzung_von_Pr%C3%A4position_und_bestimmtem_Artikel_im_Deutschen), in: *Redder*, Deutsche Grammatik II, 1985, S. 82-106, hier S. 94)

Die beiden Beispielsätze sind grammatisch, weil diese Anforderungen in Hinblick auf *Frau* bzw. *Qual* jeweils erfüllt sind (und zu *zu + der* eine kontrahierte Form - *zur* - existiert).

Answer (score 1):

Der Grund ist einfach

- **Zum** bedeutet *sowohl* **zu dem** als auch **zu einem**.
- **Zur** bedeutet *sowohl* **zu der** als auch **zu einer**.

In Phrasen wie

> zum Problem werden
>
> zur Qual werden

ist es *per definitionem* **zu einem/zu einer**, weil der bestimmte Artikel, wie du richtig bemerkt hast, hier keinen Sinn ergibt.

In Phrasen wie

> zum Bahnhof

ist auch höchstens aus dem Zusammenhang klar, welcher Bahnhof gemeint ist. Auch dort ist es also eigentlich *zu einem Bahnhof*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134677/discussion-on-answer-by-janka-zur-qual-werden-zur-frau-werden).

Answer (score 0):

Das Mädchen, das zur Frau wird, wird aber nicht zu irgendeiner Frau, sondern zu einer ganz bestimmten, nämlich ihrem erwachsenen Selbst. Und auch die Qual ist nicht irgendeine, sondern gerade diejenige (klar bestimmte), die aus dem folgt, das zur Qual wird. Wenn beispielsweise Radfahren zur Qual wird, dann ist das die Qual des Radfahrens, und nicht irgendeine andere Qual. Insofern macht der bestimmte Artikel hier total Sinn.

Comment: Sie haben keine Quelle geliefert, um ihre Behauptung zu unterstützen. Es ein eine wichtige Frage über die deutsche Sprache und sowas, denke ich, soll nicht unbegründet beantwortet werden.