# Lässt sich "zu einer" als "zur" umschreiben?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

Wie kommt es eigentlich, dass man bei einem Satz wie "Ich mache das zu einer Routine" das "zu einer" mit "zur" umschreiben kann? Ich dachte immer, dass "zur" lediglich eine Zusammenziehung von "zu der" wäre, doch bei dem oberen Satz würde ja "zu der Routine" keinen Sinn ergeben.

Comment: Hallo naytte2! Herzlich Willkommen auf German.SE! Ich habe deine Frage geschlossen, weil sie meiner Meinung nach bereits hier https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46152/zur-qual-werden-zur-frau-werden beantwortet wird. Falls deine Frage dort nicht beantwortet wird, kannst du deine Frage editieren, sodass der Unterschied der beiden Fragen deutlich wird. Dann würden wir deine Frage auch wieder öffnen.